# Junit - AssertArrayEquals is not working for user definded object (Non-Primitive data type)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

`assertArrayEquals` is not working for user defined class.

I have `User` class which has `name` property alone. When I create an array objects (actual & expected) for `User` class and try to test with `assertArrayEquals`, the test fails.

I am getting below error

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<cts.Learning.User@3fa77460> but was:<cts.Learning.User@619a5dff>"
```

I am using Junit - 4.12 and Hamcrest-all 1.3 version.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    public User(){} 
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;       
    }   
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }   
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class UserJunit {

    @Test
    public void testUserBO() {          
        User[] expected = new User[2];      
        expected[0] = new User("A");
        expected[1] = new User("B");

        User[] actual = new User[2];
        actual[0] = new User("A");
        actual[1] = new User("B");  
        assertArrayEquals(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `assertArrayEquals` method - after handling iteration and various other features - eventually resolves to this call:

```
expected.equals(actual)
```

So, it invokes `equals` on your `User` class and since you have not declared an `equals` method this delegates to the the default implementation of `equals` in the `Object` class which compares using the equality operator i.e. it compares the object references not their value.

So, the `assertArrayEquals` call ends up invoking:

```
actual[0] == expected[0]
```

And since they are not the same instance that assertion fails.

If you want to assert equality between these instances of `User` then you'll have to provide some definition of what it means for two instances of `User` to be equal i.e. define an `equals` method on `User`.

Here's an example:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, user.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
```

If you add the above to your `User` class then your test will pass.